# I get error couldn't find module 'ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey'

Tags: truffle, blockchain, nodejs, ethereumjs, ethereum-classic

I was running this code deploy.js

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const { interface, bytecode } = require('./compile');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    '***** ****** ********* ********************* ***********',
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/*****************'
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

  const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!'] })
    .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });

  console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

and I got this below given out.

```
node deploy.js
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Saurabh\inbox\node_modules\truffle-hdwallet-provider\index.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I am pretty sure that I have not done any typo. This some packaging issue. Does anyone have the idea how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ethereumwalletjs version > 0.6.0 has some directory problem. They have created dist folder inside the ethereumwallet and kept the hdkey.js and index.js module inside it. That's why this problem occurs. I kept it in direct location of ethereumwallet package and it worked.
Now this solution will work for every higher version greater than 0.6.0.

Comment: you answer doesn't indicate how to fix the problem. what does "I kept it in direct location of ethereumwallet package and it worked" mean?

Answer (score 7):

Update: 

`npm uninstall ethereumjs-wallet
npm uninstall truffle-hdwallet-provider
npm install --save ethereumjs-wallet@0.6.0
npm install --save truffle-hdwallet-provider@0.0.3`

Credit goes to 2 gentlemen on udemy QA Sarshad and Guang

---

I tried to install a prior version to ethereumjs-wallet (`npm install --save ethereumjs-wallet@0.5.2` or `@0.6.0`) and this time it starts running but crashes on the async/await as a warning.

No transaction either on etherscan so it seems need to use promises with prior versions < 0.6.1 of ethereumjs-wallet (haven't tried that yet).

ethereumjs-wallet@0.6.1 has a different file structure and hdkey is no longer in its root folder.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found the root cause. Ethereum version >0.6.0 has directory issue. Modules like hdkey.js index.js are not in the classpath of the ethereum-walletjs. Releasing team has made a new folder named dist and kept these module in it. So, changing the directory can also solve the problem.

Comment: @kaushik_pm its better if you can accept an answer or provide one

Answer (score 1):

As of today (2081-08-07) to get around this issue and use the latest versions you can add these to your `package.json` and it will work.

```
"dependencies": {
    ...other bits...
    "ethereumjs-wallet": "^0.6.1",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^0.0.6",
    ... other bits...
}
```

or you can update them on the command line:

```
npm install --save ethereumjs-wallet
npm install --save truffle-hdwallet-provider
```

I know people prefer to lock versions to stop issues in the future, if so, just omit the `^` at the front of the version numbers. You should get a `package-lock.json` file anyway when you install the first time which will freeze you stable version numbers anyway.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you import hdkey from the ethereumjs-wallet library. hdkey is being exported and it is not the default export.

```
const {hdkey} = require('ethereumjs-wallet');

const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic();
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);
const hdWallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);
```